# merging the contents of an array with a single value from an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having issues merging an object with the contents of an array. I want to merge the values from array1 (title only) to array. I need to also rename the field from title.

```
const array = [{ name: 'bob'},{ name: 'don' }]

const array1 = [[{ title: 'director', dob: 'xxx'}] ,[{ title: 'manager', dob: 'xxx}]]
```

I tried to do something like  this with array:

```
array.push({'new_title_name': array1.map((item) => item.title)})
```

It gave me a whole bunch of dupes and seems a little hacky.

Thanks in advance, Jimi

Comment: It's a bit confusing that array1 is an array of arrays. Might there be more than one entry in the nested array? In your example there is always exactly one entry in each nested array

Comment: There is more than one entry in that array (the first one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```js
const array = [{ name: 'bob'},{ name: 'don' }]

const array1 = [[{ title: 'director', dob: 'xxx'}] ,[{ title: 'manager', dob: 'xxx'}]]

console.log(
    array.map((el, i) => ({...el, new_title_name: array1[i][0].title }))
)
```

Comment: Hi Dave, your code works great. When I apply it to an object with a few more fields I received for some reason.
```
[
  {
    "name": "bob",
    "new_title_name": "director"
  },
  {
    "name": "don",
    "new_title_name": "director"
  }
]
```

Comment: Its reporting the index as 0 for both rows.

Comment: Ok it was PEBKAC. Thanks for your help Dave!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to update the elements, not push anything:

```js
const array = [{ name: 'bob'},{ name: 'don' }]
const array1 = [[{ title: 'director', dob: 'xxx'}] ,[{ title: 'manager', dob: 'xxx'}]]

array.forEach( (e,i) => e.new_title_name = array1[i][0].title )
console.log(array)
```